# How to save instance of FirabaseAuth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a application with a issue i've been strugling for few days. Consists on a login that then sends you to main activity where there's a button that gives you a reward(coins). This button saves on firebaseDB all the data(userID, email and number of coins). IF I leave the app and go back to it after few seconds, the app crashes because it cannot access to userID and email. The code where it crashes is this

```
 public void addCoins(View view) {

    mCoins += 5;
    user newUser = new user(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(), mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail(), mCoins); //---> Here
    mRootRef.child("UserList").child(newUser.getUid()).setValue(newUser);
}
```

I believe I could store store the uid and the email on a file, but that's what i dont wanna do. I think I could also save the instance, but i'm not sure how to do that. If somebody could help me, I would appreciate.

Thanks

Edit:

FirebaseAuth initialization:

```
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
     final FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
     /*Rest of the code ....*/
}
```

and the log trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.capie.clashgems.MainActivity.addCoins(MainActivity.java:244)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Attemp to invoke virutal method on null reference. I believe it's because of what I mentioned before, the variable gets empty when leaving the app for few seconds.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Also please add code where you create FirebaseAuth instance.

Comment: Code and stack trace added.

Comment: `getCurrentUser` returning `null` means that a user isn't signed in. You should be having code that redirects such users to a login flow right? You can't get the UID or email when the user isn't logged in.

Comment: You can use the authListener to know if the current user is null or not, it will handle properly the exception and you can manage what to do in the case that mAuth.getCurrentUser() is null

Comment: Also, please try enabling Smart Lock, as mentioned in the FirebaseAuth [docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#smart-lock). This should attempt to automatically sign in the user on revisiting the app, unless they manually signed out.

Comment: @TheGamer007 right, i have on 'onCreate()' . Will try adding the listener on the 'addCoins()' and let you know.